# Parsing xml attribute value from specified node area

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML which follow the following structure:

```
<model uir="model1">
 <profile>
  <profiles>
   <timeseries>
     <value double="24.7" index="2011-01-01 00:00" />
     <value double="24.5" index="2011-01-02 00:00" />
     <value index="2011-04-23 00:00" /> //Here for some reason i must have double=null
     <value index="2011-04-24 00:00" />
     <value double="24.7" index="2011-01-01 00:00" />
     <value double="24.5" index="2011-01-02 00:00" />

    </timeseries>
   </profile>
  </profiles>
 </model>
<model uir="model2">
 <profile>
  <profiles>
   <timeseries>
     <value double="24.7" index="2011-01-01 00:00" />
     <value double="24.5" index="2011-01-02 00:00" />
     <value index="2011-04-23 00:00" /> //Here for some reason i must have double=null
     <value index="2011-04-24 00:00" />
     <value double="24.7" index="2011-01-01 00:00" />
     <value double="24.5" index="2011-01-02 00:00" />

    </timeseries>
   </profile>
  </profiles>
 </model>
```

This that i want is to take the value of the attribute **double** and to store it in a list (or vector) for each model. When the node **value** hasn't an attribute double to insert a null. In first level i tried the following but when it reaches in a node with no attribute double stack.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class MyClass
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        string file = @"C:\RDMS.xml";
        XDocment doc = XDocument.Load(file);
        foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("value"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("double").Value);
        }
       Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify the error, but I am guessing you are getting a `NullReferenceException`? You need to check if `item.Attribute` actually returns a value.

```
var doubleAttr = item.Attribute("double");
if(doubleAttr == null) continue;
Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("double").Value);
```

If that is not your problem, then please be more specific as to what your problem is.

Further clarification from trope's comment below:

> ...you are getting a NullReferenceException because nothing returns from item.Attribute("double") for the elements that lack that attribute, therefore you cannot then call .Value, as item.Attribute("double") is null, and you receive a NullReferenceException. This does not happen with your index attribute, because all of your "value" elements have index attributes...

Comment: blocks the debugging and gives the exception that you mentioned. When i replace the attribute with "index" working fine and print on the screen all index values. It stacks with double i.e print 24.7 24.5 and then the exception!

Comment: Then my solution (or a variation for what you need) should work

Comment: Just to be clear, @amigo, you are getting a NullReferenceException because nothing returns from item.Attribute("double") for the elements that lack that attribute, therefore you cannot then call .Value, as item.Attribute("double") is null, and you receive a NullReferenceException. This does not happen with your index attribute, because all of your "value" elements have index attributes. Justin's solution should be sufficient to overcome this problem.

Comment: @trope +1 Thanks. I guess I made a possibly bad assumption that everybody understood NRE :) Do you mind if I move your elaboration into my answer (with credit of course)?

Comment: Yes thanks that solves the problem. I wanted to have a list or vector with [24 25 null null 24 25]. I will fix it. Thanks again for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the result of `Attribute(string)` if it is `null`:

```
var attrib = item.Attribute("double");
if (attrib != null)
    Console.WriteLine(attrib.Value);
else
    Console.WriteLine("attribute not found!");
```